# Can't add CNAME domain to Azure Websites where the domain name has a number, in it

Tags: azure

I've read other questions before posting this one, none of them is having the solution to what im facing. Im not new to Azure websites and already have a few websites running already but this one in particular is being a pain. I have a domain something like www.abc2wxyz.com (sorry can't reveal the name). I have made the required CNAME with awverify and awverify.www but still even after 24hrs Azure keeps giving me abc2wxyz.com or www.abc2wxyz.com. On the other hand if i add another domain called abc-wzyx.com it gets added. Could this be due to the first domain containing numerics? or is this something else?

Also whenever i visit my domain abc2wxyz.com i get that blue Azure 404 image which shows that the domain's CNAME have infact propogated and all that is left is adding it to the respected Azure Website.

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "Azure keeps giving me abc2wxyz.com or www.abc2wxyz.com".

Comment: Those are just dummy domain names that are meant to resemble the original domain name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess problem was due to the fact that I had a number in my domain name e.g. www.abc**2**wxyz.com but as soon as i got a domain that was www.abc**to**wxyz.com it started working. Im not sure what the problem might be but if you know, i would be happy to know about it.

Thanks!

Comment: This should work.  Sounds like a bug, why don't you open a ticket with Microsoft?

Comment: I don't have a paid support on Azure so i can't open ticket there. Can you point me to some other link?

Comment: I'm finding out now that if i have a domain with a number in it, I can't do password reset on users in that domain.